# Infinite Loop with DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a "list" of local users in a computer. I execute this code :

```
public void ConnexionAD()
{
    string PC = "WinNT://localhost";
    using(var computerEntry = new DirectoryEntry(PC))
    {
        foreach(DirectoryEntry childEntry in computerEntry.Children)
        {
            if(childEntry.SchemaClassName == "User")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(childEntry.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, it works, I obtain my local users but i can't take controle of my graphical interface (MAINWINDOW), like if there is an infinite loop

I call this method with a button.

I've got 4 results, but I can't take control of MainWindow

If I put a "Console.WriteLine("End") after foreach loop, it's not writing.

Have you got any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What "graphical interface" is this? Does the loop *actually* complete? Do you know how many entries it's iterating over? Please give us more information.

Comment: How do you call the method? Did you check how often the method is called via breakpoints?

Comment: You may have links in the file structure that create infinite loops.  Like a like from a child directory to its parent.

Comment: Your problem is not clear.  This code works fine.  If you can [edit] your problem to include more detail, it would be helpful.

Comment: My problem is edited.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: what happens when you debug? try to put a watch after the last element of  computerEntry.Children

Comment: I run your code and it works well =.=

Comment: I run this code in Windows 8.1, a friend try this code in Windows 7 and he has the same issue...he tries on Windows xp...and it works fine...i don't know why

Comment: If a put after this code after if {} : 'else  { break; } ' it works...but it's not a good issue for me...what do you think about that ?